# Creating ElasticSearch 6.5 nested boolean queries from SQL

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've this quite simple SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
((sphereMin>=-17 AND sphereMax<=5) OR sphereMin<=-17)
AND
((sphereMax<=5 AND sphereMax>=-17) OR sphereMax>=5)
```

I have to translate that query to ES using high level API.
This is the relevant code:

```
 SearchSourceBuilder searchBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
 BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = boolQuery();

 BoolQueryBuilder booleanQuery1 = boolQuery();
 BoolQueryBuilder subQuery1a = boolQuery();
 booleanQuery1.must(subQuery1a);
 RangeQueryBuilder subQuery1b = null;

subQuery1a.must(rangeQuery("sphereMin").gte(-17));
subQuery1a.must(rangeQuery("sphereMax").lte(5));
subQuery1b = rangeQuery("sphereMin").lte(-17);

booleanQuery1.should(subQuery1b);

BoolQueryBuilder booleanQuery2 = boolQuery();
BoolQueryBuilder subQuery2a = boolQuery();
booleanQuery2.must(subQuery2a);
RangeQueryBuilder subQuery2b = null;

subQuery2a.must(rangeQuery("sphereMax").gte(-17));
subQuery2a.must(rangeQuery("sphereMax").lte(5));
subQuery2b = rangeQuery("sphereMax").gte(5);

booleanQuery2.should(subQuery2b);

boolQueryBuilder.filter(booleanQuery1);
boolQueryBuilder.filter(booleanQuery2);
searchBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
SearchRequest searchRequest = Requests.searchRequest(indexName).allowPartialSearchResults(true)
                .source(searchBuilder).routing(routing);
```

The JSON created from that code is:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [     
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                  {
                    "range" : {
                      "sphereMin" : {
                        "from" : "-17",
                        "to" : null,
                        "include_lower" : true,
                        "include_upper" : true,
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range" : {
                      "sphereMax" : {
                        "from" : null,
                        "to" : "5",
                        "include_lower" : true,
                        "include_upper" : true,
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "should" : [
            {
              "range" : {
                "sphereMin" : {
                  "from" : null,
                  "to" : "-17",
                  "include_lower" : true,
                  "include_upper" : true,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                  {
                    "range" : {
                      "sphereMax" : {
                        "from" : "-17",
                        "to" : null,
                        "include_lower" : true,
                        "include_upper" : true,
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range" : {
                      "sphereMax" : {
                        "from" : null,
                        "to" : "5",
                        "include_lower" : true,
                        "include_upper" : true,
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "should" : [
            {
              "range" : {
                "sphereMax" : {
                  "from" : "5",
                  "to" : null,
                  "include_lower" : true,
                  "include_upper" : true,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

It looks right to me but that query doesn't return the same data of the SQL query.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe not important but in your code you have a case mistake "MIn" : subQuery1a.must(rangeQuery("sphereMIn").gte(-17));

Comment: @LeBigCat Sorry, just a wrong copy and past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case

```
booleanQuery1.must(subQuery1a);
```

should probably be

```
booleanQuery1.should(subQuery1a);
```

as well as

```
booleanQuery2.must(subQuery2a);
```

should also be

```
booleanQuery2.should(subQuery2a);
```

Example:

```
qb.should(a);
qb.should(b);
qb.should(c);
```

per default means, that at least one of these conditions has to match: `a OR b OR c` while

```
qb.must(a);
qb.should(b);
```

means that a *must* match, and b *should*.

Answer (score 0):

```
((sphereMax<=5 AND sphereMax>=-17) OR sphereMax>=-17)

ubQuery2a.must(rangeQuery("sphereMax").gte(-17));
subQuery2a.must(rangeQuery("sphereMax").lte(5));
subQuery2b = rangeQuery("sphereMax").gte(5);
```

5 instead of -17

;)

Comment: sorry just a wrong copy and past. I edited my question